# How do you combine ES6 rest operator with default params?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function called getEntries.

```
function getEntries(config = defaultConfig, contentTypeFilter = defaultContentTypes) {
      // defaultContentTypes is an Array
}
```

I'd like getEntries to be called without passing an array literal.

```
getEntries(config, 'blogPosts', 'pages');
```

Internally, I would still like to treat it as an array using the rest operator:

```
function getEntries(config = defaultConfig, ...contentTypeFilter = defaultContentTypes)
```

But I'm getting an error pointing to the = sign presumably because of the way I'm trying to combine them or because they can't be combined:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected )
```

I'm aware that I can set a default internally using the OR operator. But I'm curious if combining these two is possible.

Comment: You can't use rest with default.

Comment: A rest parameter will always evaluate to an array (empty if no arguments available). But it will always provide a value, a default initialiser would never run.

Comment: You can add in function something like `let [x=defaultContentTypes[0],y=defaultContentTypes[1]] = contentTypeFilter;` to set default values on rest data.